# Why is the import library .lib bigger than the .dll?

Tags: c++, windows, opencv, cmake, lib

In a cmake project that generates a `.dll` and corresponding `.lib` I just noticed the `.lib` is bigger than the `.dll`. How is that possible? Isn't the `.lib` supposed to be much smaller than the `.dll`?

debug

```
.lib (~870KB) and .dll (~700KB)
```

release

```
.lib (~200KB) and .dll (~200KB)
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19.1)

project(mylib)

set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})

link_libraries(${OpenCV_LIBS})

set(CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS TRUE)

add_library(mylib SHARED mylib.cpp another_lib.cpp)
```

Wondering if perhaps there is something wrong with the `CMakeLists.txt`?

And why is the `.lib` size different in debug and release builds?

```
dumpbin.exe /symbols mylib.lib
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 14.29.30133.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file mylib.lib

File Type: LIBRARY

COFF SYMBOL TABLE
000 010175B5 ABS    notype       Static       | @comp.id
001 00000000 SECT2  notype       External     | __IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR_mylib
002 C0000040 SECT2  notype       Section      | .idata$2
003 00000000 SECT3  notype       Static       | .idata$6
004 C0000040 UNDEF  notype       Section      | .idata$4
005 C0000040 UNDEF  notype       Section      | .idata$5
006 00000000 UNDEF  notype       External     | __NULL_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR
007 00000000 UNDEF  notype       External     | ⌂mylib_NULL_THUNK_DATA

String Table Size = 0x52 bytes

COFF SYMBOL TABLE
000 010175B5 ABS    notype       Static       | @comp.id
001 00000000 SECT2  notype       External     | __NULL_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR

String Table Size = 0x1D bytes

COFF SYMBOL TABLE
000 010175B5 ABS    notype       Static       | @comp.id
001 00000000 SECT2  notype       External     | ⌂mylib_NULL_THUNK_DATA

String Table Size = 0x1D bytes

  Summary

          C3 .debug$S
          14 .idata$2
          14 .idata$3
           8 .idata$4
           8 .idata$5
           C .idata$6
```

Comment: What does `dumpbin /symbols <yourlib>.lib` returns?

Comment: If I had to guess, the `.lib` file is probably a static-link library, not an import library for the DLL.

Comment: @Tsyvarev sorry, it was supposed to be `add_library(mylib SHARED mylib.cpp another_lib.cpp)`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau are you implying that CMakeLists.txt is generating a static-link library? It states `SHARED` on `add_library(mylib SHARED mylib.cpp another_lib.cpp)`.

Comment: @KcFnMi I don't use CMake, so I wouldn't know

Comment: @Wisblade question updated. Is that telling me anything?

Comment: @KcFnMi It doesn't seems that the `.lib` contains anything abnormal, at least... Similar results to one of my own lib (25 KB for LIB, 760 KB for DLL, 13 MB for PDB). The `dumpbin /all <yourlib>.lib` could tell more, but it's an awfully **HUGE** amount of text to add to your question - and, frankly, it's a pain to analyze when you don't know the library itself and don't have the source code... Try to run `dumpbin /all LakLib.d.lib | find /i "size"`, post the BEGINNING (up to "String table"). Check yourself for big numbers below "String table".

Comment: If you're requesting to have **everything** exported, then, well, the corresponding import library will explode in size. Remove `set(CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS TRUE)` from the CMake script. This property only exists to help port code from platforms that have decided to choose the wrong ("everything is public") default.

Answer (score 2):

> I just noticed the `.lib` is bigger than the `.dll`. How is that possible?

Simple math. Each export in the DLL's [.edata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format#the-edata-section-image-only) section consists of the symbol name, its 32-bit relative virtual address (RVA), and a 16-bit ordinal. That is, the length of the exported symbol plus 6 bytes. The import library, by contrast, contains (at a minimum) the symbol name, the name of the module exporting the symbol, plus file format overhead, for each symbol.

In other words: The encoding of an exported symbol takes up more space in an import library than it does in a module's export table. As you're adding exports, the import library grows faster than the module. At some point the size of the import library will exceed the size of its corresponding module.

And indeed, you're trying hard to export just about any symbol that can be exported from the CMake script:

```
set(CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS TRUE)
```

This is setting the [`WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS.html#windows-export-all-symbols) property to `TRUE`, causing every symbol (except for data symbols) to be implicitly exported.

This is generally not what you'd want, and you should remove that line from the CMake script. You'll immediately see that both the import library as well as the module will get smaller. As an added bonus this enables several linker optimizations that would otherwise be left unused.